# How to transform two Maps into a single Map

Tags: scala

Suppose I have two Maps like these

```
Map(("a" -> "x-100"), ("b" -> "x-200"), ("c" -> "x-300"))

Map(("a" -> "y-100"), ("b" -> "y-200"), ("c" -> "y-300"))
```

What would be the simplest way to transform them into the following (assuming that all the values are unique and with **possibly different lengths**)?

```
Map(("x-100" -> "y-100"), ("x-200" -> "y-200"), ("x-300" -> "y-300"))
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen if they are different lengths? Ignore the key and/or value if it can't be paired?

Comment: In those cases, the pair should be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val m1 = Map(("a" -> "x-100"), ("b" -> "x-200"), ("c" -> "x-300"),("d" -> "ignored"))

val m2 = Map(("a" -> "y-100"), ("b" -> "y-200"), ("c" -> "y-300"))

m1.keySet.intersect(m2.keySet).map(k=>m1(k)->m2(k)).toMap
```

Answer (score 4):

Or with a for comprehension and some *safety*:

```
  for{
    (k, v1) <- m1
    v2 = m2.get(k)
    if (v2.isDefined)
  } yield (v1 -> v2.get)
```

This returns `Map(x-100 -> y-100, x-200 -> y-200, x-300 -> y-300)`

Check [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/5F2Hc3P/2)

Comment: You can just do `v2 <- m1.get(k)`, delete the `if` and use `v2` rather than `v2.get`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
val a = Map(("a" -> "x-100"), ("b" -> "x-200"), ("c" -> "x-300"))
val b = Map(("a" -> "y-100"), ("b" -> "y-200"), ("c" -> "y-300"))

def zipMaps(map1: Map[String, String], map2: Map[String, String]) = {
  for(key <- map1.keys ++ map2.keys)
     yield (key, map1.get(key), map2.get(key))
}

val result = zipMaps(a,b).map{
  case (k,Some(v1),Some(v2)) => (v1,v2)
  case (k,_ ,_)=> ("", "")
}.toMap.filterKeys(_ != "")
// result = Map(x-100 -> y-100, x-200 -> y-200, x-300 -> y-300)
```

Comment: that only works if the order of the map is the same!! Check https://scalafiddle.io/sf/5F2Hc3P/0

Comment: this only fails now for the last comment of d-_-b: "In those cases, the pair should be ignored." - check https://scalafiddle.io/sf/5F2Hc3P/4

Answer (score 2):

```
val a = Map("a" -> "x-100", "b" -> "x-200", "c" -> "x-300")
val b = Map("a" -> "y-100", "b" -> "y-200", "c" -> "y-300")
val c = a.map {
  case (k, v) => v -> b(k)
}
println(c) // Map(x-100 -> y-100, x-200 -> y-200, x-300 -> y-300)
```

Comment: this only works if you both Maps have exactly the same keys - check https://scalafiddle.io/sf/5F2Hc3P/1